# Python list.sort() and sorted() equivalent

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting

This question is strictly for learning. I doubt I will need to use it since sort() and sorted() exists, but I would like to learn the algorithm/approach used in here.

We have an array like so:

```
test = [
    [2, 2], 
    [1, 2], 
    [1, 1], 
    [3, 3], 
    [1, 3], 
    [2, 3], 
    [3, 2], 
    [2, 1], 
    [3, 1]
]
```

I want to sort by the second number, then by the first or vice versa.

Normally I would do it using `sorted()`:

```
test = sorted(test, key=lambda x: (x[1], x[0]))
```

Or in place using `list.sort()`:

```
test.sort(key=lambda x: (x[1], x[0]))
```

How can this be done without using any of the methods above.

Comment: By writing your own sort method, using a standard sorting algorithm.

Comment: I recommend you pick a sorting algorithm from here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm and try to implement it yourself.

Comment: Python's sort algorithm is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort.  The idea behind how key works is explained in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform.

Comment: True, I can write a sorting algorithm, but my question is more about how to sort by the second value. In my case let's say I have [2, 2], [2, 1], [1, 1]. If I sort it by second number I will get [2, 1], [1, 1], [2, 2]. Now I want to sort by first number to get [1, 1], [2, 1], [2, 2]. Is there a way to doing previous sort or do I have to sort it again by second number. Wouldn't it break original sort? Or is there a better way to do that? Let me know if it makes sense

Comment: So you are not asking for a sort algorithm and you don't want to use the built-in sorting functions, yet you want to sort. I am lost.

Comment: I want to understand how build-in sorting function does the sequence of sorting. How do I need to use any sorting algorythm to sort it by 2 parameters instead of 1. In case when objects have equal first value, how do I sort them by second value. Sorry if I am unclear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual implementation is at [list_sort_impl](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/listobject.c#L2192).

Here is a pure Python implementation of something similar (though less optimized, etc).

First we need a simple helper function:

```
def cmp (a, b):
    if a < b:
        return 1
    elif a == b:
        return 0
    else:
        return -1
```

When comparing two integers, it just does integer comparison.  When comparing strings it does string comparison.  When comparing lists and tuples, it compares the first slot, then the second slot, then the third, until it finds a non-equal comparison and returns that.  (Or finds that they are all equal.)

For demonstration purposes we do not need to implement this since `le((1, 2, 3), (1, 3, 2))` already does the right thing.  If you want to implement your own class and have it have a different ordering, see https://portingguide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/comparisons.html for how to do that.

And now let's implement a simple sort algorithm.  I'll do merge sort and pass in an explicit comparison operator.

```
def _merge (array1, array2, _le):
    i = 0
    j = 0
    answer = []
    while i < len(array1) and j < len(array2):
        if _le(array1[i], array2[j]):
            answer.append(array1[i])
            i += 1
        else:
            answer.append(array2[j])
            j += 1

    while i < len(array1):
        answer.append(array1[i])
        i += 1

    while j < len(array2):
        answer.append(array2[j])
        j += 1

    return answer

def _sorted (array, _le):
    if len(array) < 2:
        return array.copy()
    else:
        k = len(array) // 2
        return _merge(
                _sorted(array[0:k], _le),
                _sorted(array[k:], _le),
                _le
            )

def mysorted (array, key=None, reversed=False):
    _le = le

    if key is not None:
        # Turn the array into pairs of (to_compare, orig)
        array = [(key(x), x) for x in array]
        # Extract compare first pair
        _le = lambda a, b: le(a[0], b[0])

    if reversed:
        _ge = lambda a, b: a == b or not _le(a, b)
        sorted_array = _sorted(array, _ge)
    else:
        sorted_array = _sorted(array, _le)

    if key is not None:
        # Return the orig values in order.
        return [x[1] for x in sorted_array]
    else:
        # All done
        return sorted_array
```

If you test it out, `mysorted` should work just like `sorted`, only slower.

And you can see, part of the magic is buried in turning the array into to_compare/orig pairs, comparing the part you are supposed to compare, and then extracting the original.

And another part of the magic is in the fact that comparison on tuples cascades from start to finish.

Comment: I see, that makes more sense to me now. Thank you very much for your answer!